# CollectionView SelectedItem BindableProperty

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have collection view and I would like to get to the detail page. However I am using BindableObject class Xamarin forms which works fine

So create property and then use it like this

```
public BindableProperty DiagnosticEventProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(Logs),
        returnType: typeof(ObservableCollection<JsonLogEvent>),
        defaultValue: new ObservableCollection<JsonLogEvent>(),
        declaringType: typeof(DiagnosticInfoViewModel));
    
    public ObservableCollection<JsonLogEvent> Logs
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<JsonLogEvent>) GetValue(DiagnosticEventProperty);
        set => SetValue(DiagnosticEventProperty, value);
    }
```

Hoever I am not sure how to work this with the selected item?

My Xaml

```
<CollectionView HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLogs }"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Logs, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <templates:DiagnosticEventPageTemplate />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ItemsScoure** specifies the collection of items to be displayed, besides setting binding for the **ItemsScoure** property, we also need to set binding for the template using the model class(it should be JsonLogEvent class).

For example, the 'JsonLogEvent' class contains the 'TheContent' parameter and we set binding for a `Label` with the parameter.

Check the code:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding TheContent}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

According to the posted code, it seems you use a custom layout. To use the custom layout in a collectionView, please set binding for the custom control like:

```
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApplication_5.CustomLayout">
    <Label Text="{Binding TheContent}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Referce the custom layout:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomTemplate />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```